# Change background color of JavaScript canvas animation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I found this fantastic HTML5 fire animation online [credit: iBasskung on YouTube] and I'm trying to figure out how to make the black background transparent. I'm an intermediate JS coder but it seems like the background is part of the fire and needs an opacity of 0.

I've examined the color array and flame renderer, but I don't see any hex or rgba values anywhere.

Thoughts on how to extricate the black bg from the flames themselves?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/qsu6ma18/)

```
// color array
for (i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    colors[i][2] = i << 1;
    colors[i + 32][0] = i << 3;
    colors[i + 32][2] = 64 - (i << 1);
    colors[i + 64][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 64][1] = i << 3;
    colors[i + 96][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 96][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 96][2] = i << 2;
    colors[i + 128][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 128][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 128][2] = 64 + (i << 2);
    colors[i + 160][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 160][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 160][2] = 128 + (i << 2);
    colors[i + 192][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 192][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 192][2] = 192 + i;
    colors[i + 224][0] = 255;
    colors[i + 224][1] = 255;
    colors[i + 224][2] = 224 + i;
  }

// render the flames
for (let y = skipRows; y < canvasHeight; ++y) {
  for (x = 0; x < canvasWidth; ++x) {
    index = y * canvasWidth * 4 + x * 4;
    let value = fire[(y - skipRows) * canvasWidth + x];

    data[index] = colors[value][0];
    data[++index] = colors[value][1];
    data[++index] = colors[value][2];
    data[++index] = 255;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is understanding how setting/getting pixels works in canvas. Both `getImageData` and `putImageData` work with pixel values in a 1D array. You can see this in your code with the `data` array:

```
// red value 0-255
data[index] = colors[value][0];

// green value 0-255
data[++index] = colors[value][1];

// blue value 0-255
data[++index] = colors[value][2];

// alpha value 0-255
data[++index] = 255;
```

Because the fire has a full red value close to `255` you can just use the red channel for your alpha as well.

```
// alpha value 0-255
data[++index] = colors[value][0];
```

Here is a working version of your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jq6urawb/